# In Jmeter - How can i get, how much time taken to navigate a page

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

While navigating to e.x landing page the blazemeter recorder gives 10 HTTP requests. In this case, how can i get, how much time taken to navigate landing page.
If I summarize all the requests time based on View Results in Table listener, it is more than the reponse time of chrome time hence couldn't get the exact time.

Note: HTTP Request might be sequential or parallel.

Chrome Response time is 4sec but View Results in Table listener sum value is 12sec

Comment: All 10 requests are executed one after another. Hence it does not simulate the actual execution by the browser. Samplers are executed in the order they appear in the test plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have 10 requests, most probably you should have only 1 request.

If remaining 9 requests are for images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. - you don't need to add them manually, instead you need to tick `Retrieve all embedded resources` and `Parallel Downloads` boxes on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better, HTTP Request Defaults:

[image]

If the requests are [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) - you need to put them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

Comment: I have 10 requests and i checked Retrieve all embedded resource option also

Comment: You need to check the checkbox only in the main sampler. You can disable the samplers requesting the images, CSS , JS and other resources.