# In Jmeter - How to get time taken to load a page

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

While navigating to e.x landing page the blazemeter recorder gives 10 HTTP requests. In this case, how can I get, how much time taken to navigate landing page. And which one I need to refer from below.

- Avg value in Agg Report is 5 sec
- 90% value in Agg Report is 5.5 sec
- Sum of all the requests time in View Results in Table listener is 32 sec

Above times are more than the response time of chrome time hence couldn't get the exact time.

Note: HTTP Request might be sequential or parallel. So I checked Retrieve all embedded resource option also.

Chrome Response time is 14 sec but View Results in Table listener sum value is 32 sec.

Comment: You have already asked the same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825219/in-jmeter-how-can-i-get-how-much-time-taken-to-navigate-a-page. Do not ask the same question again

Comment: I didn not get clear answer hence explained.

Answer (score 0):

Given you properly configure [JMeter in order to behave like the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), i.e.:

1. You're sending the same number of requests using the same pattern
2. Your requests have all the [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) the browser sends
3. You added [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan
4. You configured JMeter to properly handle embedded resources and [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests

You should be seeing approximately the same response time as for the browser.

Just cross-check the nature of the requests using [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) ("Network" tab or equivalent) and configure JMeter to send the same requests and ensure that JMeter really does it using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).